# QGIS virtual layer path never saved as relative

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, file-path, virtual-layer

When I try to use virtual layers in QGIS, I'm unable to use relative paths.

I've already set in the "Project Properties", in the tab "General", the "Save paths" as relative.

You can see a screenshot to illustrate the issue.

[image: Virtual layer absolute path only]

Removing the absolute path "breaks" the virtual layer.
For this reason, my *.qgs project is not portable...

How do you manage this use case?
It's due to my way of doing, is it a feature, a missing feature or a bug?

Any advice to bypass this issue is welcome

Comment: Maybe instead of using shapefiles use SpatiaLite and use a view instead of a virtual layer...?

Comment: The author's github ( he answers quickly) https://github.com/mhugo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

author here. That has not been tested. You should file a bug report.