# Save virtual layer for use in another project in QGIS

Tags: qgis, virtual-layer

I created a simple virtual layer in QGIS, combining a couple of points from a polygon layer with vertexes from a polygon layer.

I would like to export that virtual layer to be used as dynamic virtual layer in other projects where the points and polygon layers have exactly the same names.

I tried to save it as a layer definition file (.qlr). This file can be imported in another project. Unfortunately the paths are absolute instead of relative (c.f. here: [QGIS virtual layer path never saved as relative](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200620/qgis-virtual-layer-path-never-saved-as-relative)).

Comment: You want to export the resulting subset from the query as static layer? Then simply export the virtual layer to a Geopackage. Or you want to export the virtual layer as such, so that it remains dynamically? Then I think you have to export the whole project as virtual layers are saved in the project, not in the layer source. ALternatively, consider using a server database like PostGIS for your task.

Comment: thanks! Postgis would be an option, need to dig into that. I mean as dynamic virtual layer referencing to a gpkg-layer. I clarified in the post.

Comment: Not sure if that could work: defining the path as a variable (textstring) would be an option?

Comment: Why not simply recreate it in the new project, if your layer have the same name it should be as simple as copy/pasting the SQL query

Comment: Using the path as a string could be an option! Recreating the layer is not difficult. Saving as ".qlr" and adapting the paths is a matter of a couple of minutes. But I want to make it as foolproof as possible, so a QGIS user without knowledge on SQL and virtual layers can use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case the layer are named exactly the same, the can be referenced in the layer query, but should not be added as "embedded layer". Then, the qlr-file can be imported in another project. Just be aware that in case the referenced layer is renamed in QGIS, the virtual layer breaks.

[image]